# Using ui-routers's state params as a model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a simple angualr application which have dashboard that shows the different views of items. The `/dasboard/:item` is an abstract state. My valid urls are `/dasboard/item0/view0`, `/dashboard/item1/view0`, etc...
I want to track the current `item` and current `view`, without the additional code and only with the help of `ui-router.state` variable.

This part of script

```
<div class="">
    you are looking at <strong>{{$state.current.name}}</strong> of {{$state.$current.params.item.value()}}
</div>
```

is printing the current item with the current view of it. This is printing the view correctly but not the item, for which I am referring the variable `$state.$current.params.item.value()` , the corresponding url in browser is changing the accordingly but **not the text inside the `div`**, I don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

I am expecting the value I clicked on, but instead of that, I always get the default value of parameter, which is `item0`.

Here is a stripped down version of my application.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">

  <ul>
    <li><a ui-sref="dashboard.view0({item: 'item0'})">item0</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="dashboard.view0({item: 'item1'})">item1</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="dashboard.view0({item: 'item2'})">item2</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="dashboard.view0({item: 'item3'})">item3</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="dashboard.view0({item: 'item4'})">item4</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li><a ui-sref="dashboard.view0">view0</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="dashboard.view1">view1</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="" ui-view>

  </div>

  <strong></strong>
  <div class="">
    you are looking at <strong>{{$state.current.name}}</strong> of {{$state.$current.params.item.value()}}
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    angular
      .module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
      .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
          .state('dashboard',{
            url: '/dashboard/:item',
            params: {item: 'item0'},
            controller: 'myController as vm',
            abstract: true,
          })
          .state('dashboard.view0',{
            url: '/view0',
            templateUrl: 'view0.html',
            controller: 'myController as vm'
          })
          .state('dashboard.view1',{
            url: '/view1',
            templateUrl: 'view0.html',
            controller: 'myController as vm'
          });

      })
      .run(function($rootScope, $state){
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
      })
      .controller('myController', function($scope){
          $scope.items = [{'image': '','name':'item0', 'alt': 'item0_logo'},
              {'image': '','name':'item1','alt': 'item1_logo'},
              {'image': '','name':'item2','alt': 'item2_logo'},
              {'image': '','name':'item3','alt': 'item3_logo'}];
      });
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="view0.html">
    <h2>This is view0</h2>
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="view1.html">
    <h2>This is view1</h2>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you expect `item.value()` to return?

Comment: whatever link I have clicked, If I have clicked the `item2`, I expect `you are looking at dashboard.view0 of item2`, instead of it I always get the default value `item0` .

Comment: You have defined a default `params` property on the dashboard state. Remove it and try again.

Comment: That's not working, removing that  from config chop-off the end of the string, and by the way I need some default there in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $stateParams service must be specified as a state controller, and it will be scoped so only the relevant parameters defined in that state are available on the service object.

Since your `dashboard.view0` has no params, it is not showing any when you print them.

For more details see [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-routing)